# non-uniform antenna array design

Tags: z-transform, optimization

There are tons of papers discussed this topics and most of them are related to fancy optimization techniques (convex/non-convex). I am wondering if we can have a simpler way to find the antenna weights if I restrict my requirement as following:

1. Linear Array with antenna positions known at hand
2. All antennas are located on a grid. For example, four antennas are located at (0, d, 4d, 6d) where d is a fixed distance (say, half wavelength)
3. For synthesized pattern, we only care about mainlobe width and sidelobe level.

Any references are welcome

Thanks

Comment: If antenna positions are already known, what is it that you want to design/optimize? What are your degrees of freedom, what can you vary?

Comment: a lot of signal processing is related to fancy optimization. since your array is sparse, you could search on sparse FIR filter design.

Comment: @Florian The antenna positions are known and I would like to to know the weights. I know it is better to do a joint design. But searching for a good antenna positions are usually not very easy.

Comment: @YanZhu still not sure what you  mean by weights. Are you trying to do beamforming? Because you never mentioned that.